# The use of "Between" in dates. Which days are included?

Tags: prepositions, dates

When writing on a certificate "between the 28th March and the 9th April" does it mean the same as "from the 28th March to the 9th April" ?

Comment: "I will visit between the 28th March and the 9th April" doesn't mean the same as "I will visit from the 28th March to the 9th April".

Comment: I don't think there's a concensus on whether "between" is inclusive or exclusive. If you want to be clear, you say "from X through Y".

Comment: @Barmar "through" is equally obscure. Sounds like from the end of X to the end of Y but you may not intend it as that?

Comment: @Anton When someone says "Monday through Friday", no one would interpret that as meaning the end of Monday. While that could be a special case (it's recognized as being all the weekdays), I think most uses of "X through Y" are similarly inclusive of both ends.